# Does Keycloak allow obtaining id tokens via web interface

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, kubernetes, openid-connect, keycloak

I am investigating how to possibly authenticate to a Kubernetes 1.13 cluster with OpenID Connect and Keycloak. I am new to this area.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJ81eaGlN_I) YouTube video ("Use Open ID Connect for Kubernetes API server") accomplishes part of what I want. An id token is initially obtained by making a HTTP request (with `curl`) to Keycloak citing grant type [`password`](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password/). The resulting token is then subsequently used in further HTTP requests to the Kubernetes API. This works but has the disadvantage that clients directly handle users' permanent credentials.

Would it not be better if the token were issued by a secure web page that  also required authentication via Keycloak (this time with grant type authorization code) and did nothing else but displaying a new token? Such tokens (transient credentials) could then e.g. be manually copied into kubeconfigs for further use?

Does Keycloak provide such interactive web pages (next to the REST endpoints for obtaining tokens programatically) or is this out of scope? If the second, are there other standard components for such tasks?

**UPDATE** [This](https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/d65bee40cabcf886c89d1015334555540d38f12e/c6a46/images/docs/admin/k8s_oidc_login.svg) illustration from the Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/) perhaps makes more clear what I am seeking. In step 1 a user should log into the Identity provider to obtain tokens which can then be configured into `kubectl`. Does Keycloak support this step, i.e. offer a web page where users could log in to obtain their tokens?

Answer (score 0):

If I am able to understand your question ,so you want to get the accesstoken via Java code so here is code you can write and call

```
  String obtainAccessToken = obtainAccessToken(username, password);
  putRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + obtainAccessToken);
  putRequest.addHeader("content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Here is the method you should call

```
public String obtainAccessToken(String UserName, String pwd)
    {
        AuthzClient authzClient = AuthzClient.create(configuration);
        AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = authzClient.obtainAccessToken(UserName, pwd);
        String token = accessTokenResponse.getToken();
        return token;
    }
```

Here is the get realm method

```
public Response getAllRealms() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = JacksonObjectMapperProvider.getObjectMapper();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
        List<SureRealmRepresentation> realmList = new ArrayList<SureRealmRepresentation>();
        int status;
        try {
            String urlGetAllRealms = URL + "/admin/realms";
            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(urlGetAllRealms);
            String obtainAccessToken = obtainAccessToken(username, password);
            getRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + obtainAccessToken);
            getRequest.addHeader("content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            response = httpclient.execute(getRequest);
            status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            if (status == 200) {
                RealmRepresentation[] realmArray = mapper.readValue(responseBody, RealmRepresentation[].class);
}
catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof Exception) {
                throw (Exception) e;
            } else {
                throw ErrorHandler.wrap(new Exception("EroorType : "+ e.toString()));
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can also get the id token also with `curl`, so that's fine. What I don't have is a website where the user could obtain his token in a user-friendly way (w/o password grant). I was wondering if this a standard case with standard tools, or if one has to build such a page oneself.

Comment: @rookie099 Do you want Keycloak should provide a way to get token without providing password ? And user should enter his/her username and it will return token to user?

Comment: No, not without password, just without grant type [password grant](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password/).